# Customising UISegmentController issues

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uisegmentedcontrol, uiappearance

I am working with segemntController,

I am setting different different images for pressed and normal state of segments, below is my code

```
 (void)viewdidLoad
    {

NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"],nil];

    m_segmentController = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:imageArray];



    m_segmentController.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 212, 30);
        m_segmentController.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
            m_segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

       [m_segmentController setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [m_segmentController addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSelected:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

     [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:m_segmentController];
    }




    - (IBAction)segmentSelected:(id)sender
    {
        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
        NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

        if(selectedSegment == 0)
        {
             [m_segmentController setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
         }
         else  
          {
             [m_segmentController setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];        
          }  


        }
```

So when I start my app, the segmentController, looks this way

[image]

but when I select any segment the selected image is not filling the entire segment and looks like this

[image]

How to solve this issue, where I am going wrong

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16982225/1305001

Answer (score 0):

you can use [idevrecipes.com/2010/12/11/custom-segmented-controls/](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/11/custom-segmented-controls/).

This link has some best customize `UISegmentControl`

***EDIT***

for your problem you have to use custom segment control. currently you can set image to your segment not background image.

> **If you want to use default UISegment control you have to make exact size image with the size of your particular segment. then you can
>   adjust image by setting ContentOffSets of a segment.**

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion, but their is no need to use any custom control for it. ios 5 has provided many options for it.